# Python3: What is an efficient way to compare a bunch of variables, if one of the comparison fails, do X otherwise do Y?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say you have 10 `v_t1, v_t2, v_t3, etc,` threshold variables and 10 variables for current values `v_c1, v_c2, v_c3, etc,`, all threshold variables contain integers, all current values contain an integer or a string of "Not found". I need to compare the thresholds against the current values. If any of the current value variables are greater than the threshold, I want to run `function_a` otherwise run `function_b`

I could write out 10 different if statements and checking their return values, with a check to see if the current value contains "Not found", but that seems wrong and inefficient. Is there a better way? Maybe compare two lists together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the list of variables is `v_list = [v_c1, v_c2, ...]`, and the list of thresholds is `t_list = [v_t1, v_t2, ...]`, you can use

```
if any(v != "Not found" and v > t for (v, t) in zip(v_list, t_list)):
    function_a()
else:
    function_b()
```

Comment: Awesome, the zip function is so useful! What if I wanted  to ignore the comparison of the "Not found string"?

Comment: Then just remove `v != "Not found" and `.

Comment: Thanks, if I wanted to ignore certain values would I have to break out the logic into if statements then?

Comment: If you need to change the logic of comparison, just change the `v != "Not found" and v > t` part accordingly.

Comment: Gotcha. The comparison logic doesn't seem to be working right for me, this is what I'm seeing, output and compare code: https://hastebin.com/sukazuneka.pl

Comment: Your values in that specific example are strings. You need to convert them to integers when doing comparisons. Replace v > t with int(v) > int(t).

Comment: Great, I was thinking that was the case, what if I want it to skip the conversion of strings to integers if it comes across "Not found"? Since it will error out trying to convert letters to integers. Would I search through the list and convert "Not found" to a null value like ' ' ?

Comment: The code compares with "Not found" before converts to integer when doing int(v) > int(t). So it is safe as long as each value is either exactly "Not found" or just an integer in string.

Comment: Ah okay! Great, for future reference for me or others the if statement became - 


 if any(v != "Not found" and int(v) > int(t) for (v, t) in zip(list_of_current_values, list_of_thresholds)):

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of thresholds and a list of corresponding values, you could make a list of threshold-value pairs, using namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Pair = namedtuple('Pair', ['threshold', 'value'])
pairs = [Pair(t, v) for t, v in zip(thresholds, values)]
```

and loop over the pairs:

```
for pair in pairs:
    if pair.value != "Not found" and pair.value > pair.threshold:
        function_a()
    else:
        function_b()
```